# Why Custom Launcher doesn't work properly sometimes?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-launcher

I created a custom launcher and set it to default launcher for my tablet. but when I open an application and then press Back button I will go to the last launcher(Default launcher of Samsung) although I setup my launcher as default before!

This is my launcher manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="launcher.base.app.ehsan.com.minelauncher">

    <!-- To access internet -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the JSON's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>

    <application
        android:name=".tools.G"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.ForgetActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
            >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.RecoveryActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
            >
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".APIService.InternetService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thank you for Your answers.

Comment: try :  `@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}`

Comment: I used this in my launcher. 
But problem is that when user open an application from my launcher and press back button will go out from  my launcher!

Comment: Don't call super() in the overridden method else it will close the launcher activity.